# react-redux how to access data globally from other containers that are not children

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am not sure how to do this, i understand how to store data in  components but when creating `containers` etc it gets confusing as they need to be rendered but i just want to store data. online official docs are not very clear.

I would like to store the data in `setstate` globally so i can access it from any component. this will be related to all user information. so i can import User state and then say `user.isGuest` etc.

I currently do the the following in my header file but i need to expose the user data to any component without doing callbacks and passing data back to `App`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {getHttpRequestJSON} from '../components/HTTP.js'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchActiveUser } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';   

class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            version: ''
        };
    }

    initData = () => {
        let self = this;

        getHttpRequestJSON('/api/user/get/user/method/is/guest/format/json?quiet=1')
        .then((response) => {
            let isGuest = response.body.recordset.record.isGuest;
            if(isGuest){
                /*$(".logo").trigger('click');
                //$("#overlay").show();
                $('#modalIntro').modal('toggle');

                $("#modalIntro").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
                    $(".logo").trigger('click');
                });*/
            }

            self.props.activeUser.isGuest = isGuest;
            self.setState({
                 loading : false,
                 version : response.header.version
            });
        })
        .catch(error => { 
            console.log("Failed!", error);
            //$('#myModalError .modal-body').html(error);
            //$('#myModalError').modal('show');
        }); 
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchActiveUser();       
        this.initData();
     }

    render() {
        if(this.state.loading){
            return (
                    <div className="container-fluid" id="top_section">
                        <div id="flash_alert" className="row" style={{margin:"0 auto"}} >
                            <div className="alert alert-success col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
                              <strong>Success!</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div className="alert alert-info col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
                              <strong>Info!</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div className="alert alert-warning col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
                              <strong>Warning!</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div className="alert alert-danger col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
                              <strong>Danger!</strong>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="logo">

                        </div>
                        <div className="row-fluid">
                            <div className="header">
                                <div className="row-fluid">
                                    <div className="col-xs-5 col-sm-7 col-md-9">
                                    <h2 style={{paddingLeft: "15px !important"}} className="ellipsis">Home</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 vcenter hidden-print" style={{textAlign: "right",fontSize: "8pt",bottom: "-28px",position: "relative",float: "right"}}>
                                        <span className="username"></span> | <Link className="logout" to={`/logout`}> Logout <img src="/images/page-layout/logout-button.gif" alt="Icon: Logout" title="Logout" /> </Link>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row-fluid" style={{clear: "both",position: "relative",top: "-50px",marginLeft: "95px"}}>
                                <div className="col-sm-8"> </div>
                                <div className="col-sm-4 text-right">
                                    <Link to={`/home`}> Connectivity Compliance Portal (CCP) <span style={{fontSize:"7pt"}}></span> </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="myModalError" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                              <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header alert alert-danger">
                                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                                  <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                  Unexpected error occured
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                        );
        }
        return (
                <div className="container-fluid" id="top_section">
                    <div id="flash_alert" className="row" style={{margin:"0 auto"}} >
                        <div className="alert alert-success col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
                          <strong>Success!</strong>
                        </div>

                        <div className="alert alert-info col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
                          <strong>Info!</strong>
                        </div>

                        <div className="alert alert-warning col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
                          <strong>Warning!</strong>
                        </div>

                        <div className="alert alert-danger col-xs-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 text-center">
                          <strong>Danger!</strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="logo">

                    </div>
                    <div className="row-fluid">
                        <div className="header">
                            <div className="row-fluid">
                                <div className="col-xs-5 col-sm-7 col-md-9">
                                <h2 style={{paddingLeft: "15px !important"}} className="ellipsis">Home</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 vcenter hidden-print" style={{textAlign: "right",fontSize: "8pt",bottom: "-28px",position: "relative",float: "right"}}>

                                            <span className="username">{this.props.activeUser.name}{` `}</span> | <Link className="logout" to={`/logout`}> Logout <img src="/images/page-layout/logout-button.gif" alt="Icon: Logout" title="Logout" /> </Link>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="row-fluid" style={{clear: "both",position: "relative",top: "-50px",marginLeft: "95px"}}>
                            <div className="col-sm-8">
                                                </div>
                            <div className="col-sm-4 text-right">
                                <Link to={`/home`}>Connectivity Compliance Portal (CCP)<span style={{fontSize:"7pt"}}>{` `}v{` `}{this.state.version}</span></Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="myModalError" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header alert alert-danger">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                              <h4 class="modal-title">Error</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              Unexpected error occured
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>

        );

    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    // Whatever is returned will show up as props
    // inside of the component
    return {
        activeUser: state.activeUser
    };
}

// Anything returned from this function will end up as props
// on this container
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    // Whenever getUser is called, the result should be passed
    // to all our reducers
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchActiveUser }, dispatch);
}

//Promote component to a container - it needs to know
//about this new dispatch method, fetchActiveUser. Make it available
//as a prop
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header);
```

I have another container which i would like to access the data of `fetchActiveUser`.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchContents } from '../actions';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fetchActiveUser } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';   

class HomeContent extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchContents();
    }

    htmlDecode(input){
        let e = document.createElement('div');
        e.innerHTML = input;
        return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    }

    renderContent(classname) {
        return _.map(this.props.content, c => {

            if(c.target == classname){
                return (                        
                    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: c.content}} />
                );
            }
        });
    }

    render() {
console.log(this.props);
        return (
                <div className="container-fluid">

        <div className="row-fluid text-center" >
            <div className="panel panel-default disclaimer">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <h3 className="panel-title">INTRODUCTION</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body panel_introduction">{this.renderContent('panel_introduction')}</div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div className="row-fluid text-center top-buffer">
            <div className="panel panel-default disclaimer">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <h3 className="panel-title">Whats New!</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body panel_whats_new">{this.renderContent('panel_whats_new')}</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="row-fluid text-center top-buffer">
            <div className="panel panel-default disclaimer">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    <h3 className="panel-title">DISCLAIMER</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="panel-body panel_disclaimer">{this.renderContent('panel_disclaimer')}</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="modalIntro" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
          <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 className="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Welcome to the Connectivity Compliance Portal (CCP)</h4>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                You are receiving this message as you are a guest and require elevated privileges to make best use of the service. In order to do this you'll need to:
                    <ol start="1">
                      <li>Go to <a target="_blank" href="https://iam.domain.com/identity" target="_blank" >WIAM (https://iam.domain.com/identity)</a></li>
                      <li>Click on <i>"Request Access"</i> at the top</li>
                      <li>Search for <i>"CCP"</i></li>
                      <li>Select the relevant group and add it to the cart</li>
                      <li>Check Out!</li>
                    </ol>

                <p>You can confirm if you have been added to the group by going to <Link to={`/ldapuser`}>https://ccp.domain.com/ldapuser</Link>. Once you see you have been added to the group log out of CCP and log back in and you should have the correct permissions. The process can take a few hours to a couple of days depending on how long the approvers take.</p>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
          );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { content: state.content }
}

//Anything returned from this function will end up as props
//on this container
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
 // Whenever getUser is called, the result should be passed
 // to all our reducers
 return bindActionCreators({ fetchContents, fetchActiveUser }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

React component state and redux state are two different things. The state from redux is a global state instance, and you connect parts of this state to your React components using the `connect` hoc.

So if you want to share user state between two components, you simply `connect` those two components with the same redux state selectors.
The result of the redux state selector will be passed as props to your react component. (hence the name `mapStateToProps` commonly used to map redux state to your component props).

After your fetch, you can trigger an action using the dispatch function of react-redux.

```
dispatch({
    type: 'DATA_RECEIVED',
    payload: {
       source:<your source>,
       data: <the data>,
    }      
 })
```

Then create a reducer and add it to your root reducer:

```
export default (state ={}, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
     case 'DATA_RECEIVED': 
        return {
           ...state,
           [action.payload.source]: {
              ...state[action.payload.source],
              ...data
           }
        }
     default: return state;
  }
}
```

Then select the state in your component:

```
connect((state,props)=> state.yourReducerLocation[props.resource])(YourComponent)
```

This uses the props arg to `connect`, so you can specify `resource` on `YourComponent`.

A couple of things:

1. you should create your actions using const values and actionCreators (functions emitting an action)
2. you should think about how your reducer will store the state retrieved
3. for selecting data you should use a `mapStateToProps` function
4. `dispatch` is automatically added when using `connect` with only a state selector, but it's better to add a `dispatchToProps` object method to automatically wrap your actionCreators with a `dispatch` function
5. For efficient selectors you should use reselect
6. For side-effects (i.e. loading async data) use a side-effect middleware, something like 'redux-saga'.

Comment: i understand they are 2 different state. but what if i want to use the return data of redux state in another container. i dont want to fetch the same data again using api calls

Comment: simply add this data to the redux store using an action and reducer and select this data from the other component.
But I would use `redux-saga` for this (separation of concerns)

Comment: im not sure how to do this?